# Why isn't Android WebView rendering CSS accurately?

Tags: android, html, css, webview

Before anyone thinks this is a simple question or is a possible duplicate, please read the full post.

I'm developing an Android application and have implemented a WebView to act as part of the application. The WebView shows content from a website which is made with bootstrap and is mobile friendly. However, the CSS messes up here and there and as a result, the entire application looks odd and elements seem to be 'out of place'.

For example, I place a box and some text inside a container and place it specifically using CSS margins. Like below:

```css
.testcontainer {
border: 1px solid red;
height: 50px
width: 100%;
}
.testcontainer .box {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
background-color: blue;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}
.testcontainer .text {
font-size: 16px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="testcontainer">
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="text">Testing</div>
</div>
```

Now all is good on a MacBook Safari and Opera browser and the text's border is pixel perfect and is aligned with the top of the blue box etc. However, on the WebView inside the application, the text is around 2px off and in some cases, 5px and so on. Why? I've tried to use em instead of px for font-size but the same issue occurs. What am I missing?

Comment: can you add a screenshot? and when you say **WebView inside the application** you mean on an Android device? what are you using to test this?

Comment: Yes, I mean on an Android device. I'm using a Galaxy S5 as a physical test device. All that happens is the box is around 2px off in comparison to a laptop/desktop browser. I believe the cause is something to do with the pixel density of the mobile device.

Comment: did you try to adjust the `line-height:` and see if that make any difference ?

Comment: Yes. I've even placed 2 boxes together side by side on the laptop/desktop browser, pixel perfectly, but in my WebView the box on the right is 1px over the box on the left.